# Using brackets in defining variables in python

Tags: python

I'm learning python and I see a new thing when I read a tkinter programming book. That defined some variables in this way:

```py
input_args["text"] = label
```

I don't know what does it mean? This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That is a dictionary.

Comment: it is a way(using dictionaries) to set its properties

Answer (score 0):

Those are “dictionaries”. You can read all about them at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries